Question from Lance's book: a Hilbert module that doesn't equal to "orthogonal decomposition"
In Lance's book on Hilbert modules, an example of Hilbert module which is not equal to "orthogonal decomposition". To be more precise...
Let $A=C(X)$, a $\mathrm{C}^*\!$ algebra of continuous functions on $X$, and let $Y$ be a nonempty closed subset of $X$ whose complement is dense in $X$. Let $E=A$ and let $F=\{f\in A| f(Y)=0\}$. I want to check that in this case $F^\perp\overset{\text{by def}}{=}\{y\in E|\langle x,y\rangle=0\;(x\in F)\}=\{0\}$ and $E$ is not equal to $F\bigoplus F^\perp$.
My strategy is as follows: Fix $g\in F^\perp$. It suffices to show that $||g||=0$. And I tried to show that by calculating
$||g||=\sup\{||\langle g,f\rangle||;f\in E,||f||\leqq1\}=\sup\{||\langle g,f\rangle||;f\in F^c,||f||\leqq1\}$
but I failed. If someone with a good idea, could you give me a hint or a solution to this problem?
Thanks!

You’re over-complicating this. $\langle f, g \rangle = \overline{f}g$ by definition, so any $g \in F^\perp$ must satisfy $\overline{f}g = 0$ whenever $f(Y) = 0$. Now, fix any $x \in X \setminus Y$. By Urysohn’s lemma there is a function $f$ with $f(Y) = 0$ and $f(x) = 1$, so $\overline{f}g = 0$ and thus $g(x) = 0$. This holds for all $x \in X \setminus Y$. But $X \setminus Y$ is dense in $Y$, so $g = 0$.

Why is there again a downvoter? What exactly is the problem with my answer this time?

Thanks for your comment! As you pointed out, I was totally lost...
